# Myob - AccountRight Live Api v2 Skip login screen

Tags: oauth, myob

I am using accountright Live api v2 by MYOB. I want to get access token without going to login screen. When I send a CURL request to obtain access token i am redirected to myob login screen, how to skip that? The request I am sending is to url:

'https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/v2/authorize'

and params sent are:

```
Array
(
    [client_id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [client_secret] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [scope] => CompanyFile
    [code] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [redirect_uri] => http://myappcodeonmydomain.com
    [grant_type] => authorization_code
)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, see the accepted answer below. This is how the flow works. You just have to login the first time and then just use the refresh token every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your initial request to the API to get the access token, you should also be provided with a refresh token. Access tokens expire after a period of time, and need to be refreshed.

From the *Refreshing an Access Token* section in the [Authentication Documentation](http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/api-overview/authentication/):

> Access tokens have a limited life span and when you receive one you'll
>   also receive an Expiry Time for it and a Refresh Token. Once your
>   access token expires it can no longer be used to access the API. So
>   you'll need to trigger a refresh. You do this by POSTing the following
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> 'client_id' // your API Key 
> 'client_secret' // your API Secret
> 'refresh_token' // your refresh token 
> 'grant_type' // this should say refresh_token
> ```
>
> To this url: https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
>
> Note: while the data is formatted into a URL Query String you **do not**
>   pass the information via the URL (that would be a GET request), you
>   **must** pass the query string in the **body** and **POST** this to
>   https://secure.myob.com/oauth2/v1/authorize

As an example, I store my access and refresh tokens in a database, along with an expected expiry time 10 minutes in the future.  If a request is going to be made after that time, I call the refresh procedure to update the access token, and am able to proceed on my merry way without needing to show the login prompt each time.

You do need to have it shown at least once to find out which user is logging in, and the GUID of the Company File to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the first time auth, then there is no way to do it. You have to redirect the user to the login page by returning the url.
If you are talking about refresh the token, then it's easy. 
I'm not sure how you implement the API connection. I'm using the myob ruby sdk.
The ruby sdk is so easy to use and it will do all those auth operations for you.
:)